# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder is called even before view is visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it expected that onBindViewHolder be called before view becomes visible ? I need to log what views/indices have been seen by the user, but can't find a good way. For now, I am planning to listen for scroll events and keep checking for first and last visible views, and use the range to detect what views are visible. These calculations would be done on each scroll event - which, even after some optimizations, seems to be a bad idea.

I am using a LinearLayoutManager, with no pre-caching.

Comment: so `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` / `findLastVisibleItemPosition` should be your friends

Comment: I know the methods. I am looking for better alternatives.

Comment: whats wrong with them?

Comment: As mentioned in the post, there is nothing wrong with first/last* methods. The problem is that these methods will be triggered on each scroll (not fling).

Comment: it is called both on scroll and on fling

Comment: I guess my question is not clear enough. onScroll() is called multiple times during scroll. Even for a small scroll, it may be triggered tens of times. findFirstVisibleItemPosition() is not a light method to execute (check source code). If I add findFirstVisibleItemPosition() checks in onScroll(), scrolling performance will suffer. That's the reason I am looking for other ways to solve my problem of logging which views have been seen by user.

Comment: btw did you try `onViewAttachedToWindow` ?

Answer (score 1):

`onBindViewHolder()` is in fact always called before going in to view so that the ViewHolder is in the correct state by the time it appears. This may be a "good enough" solution as a ViewHolder is usually bound only when it's *just* out of range.

Another solution I can think of may be to simply track the distance scrolled.  Assuming each View is the same size on screen, you could track distance scrolled. If `dy > viewHeight` then you can increment your "indices viewed" counter by one. The idea being that you always start at index 0, so indices `0 - n` are already viewed right off the bat. Then, as the user scrolls down it will be `0 - n+1`, `0 - n+2` and so on. This calculation would be significantly faster than using `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` at every scroll.

You would also have to take in to account any calls to `setPosition` which would have the effect. This allows you to jump around the RecyclerView, so every time you do this you'd have to recalculate.  This is where the `findFirstVisibleItemPosition` calls would coming in handy. (You need to do this anyway because the scroll listeners aren't called).

Also, if you do any filtering in which you remove indices, this will also have an effect on the result and need to be taken in to account.

Comment: Shouldn't onBindViewHolder() be called when view is about to be shown ? So it makes sense to be called on findLastVisibleItemPosition()+1 item. But I am observing onBindViewHolder called for some more indices. My views have variable heights, but they all are at least 300dp high.

Comment: Yes. It is, but you're looking for visible. A user could scroll to item 15 out of a hundred and scroll back. Item 16 will be bound but not shown.

Comment: Actually you may be able to get away with saying that the "highest bound - 1" was visible, but there's no guarantee that the highest will be the 'last visible + 1". It's not in the contract. They could change the implementation to be "last visible + 3" and you'll be left dry (though that would be very unlikely).

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I cannot use onBind for my requirement.